# How to print string* by a class method?

Tags: string, class-method, indicator

I have a class:

```
class Person
{
    string* name;
    
     Person(string nm)
     {
       name=&nm;
     }

     void print()
     {
       cout<<"That name: "<<*name<<endl;
     }

};
```

Then:

```
main()
{
   Person first("Jack");
   
   first.print();
}
```

Console shows "Segemntation fault". Ok, but where am I wrong and how should I write this code to print that? PS. I have to use a field "string* name" in this class.

Comment: Please be sure to tag your question with the appropriate language. (I assume this is C++?)

Comment: I will remember next time. (Yes, this is C++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to do it in the class:

```
class Person
{
    string* name;
    
     Person(string* nm)
     {
       name=nm;
     }

     void print()
     {
       cout<<"That name: "<<*name<<endl;
     }

};
```

And then in funcion main:

```
main()
{
   string str_name="Jack";
   Person first(&str_name);
   
   first.print();
}
```

Now, it's all correct.

Answer (score 1):

You take take a parameter by value and then take a reference to it. At the end of the constructor the parameter is destructed, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

```
Person(string nm)
     {
       name=&nm;
     }
```

Either store the string by value instead of by pointer or store it as a const char*.